# Vulkan drivers are not working like they should causing Steam to not function as expected

Tags: steam, dual-gpu

I'm trying to play the games SimplePlanes, SimpleRockets, and Bloons TD 6, but I am on linux. I am using the Steam Play compatibility tool Proton, but Steam is stuck "launching" the game forever. Other games that have native support (ex. Team Fortress 2) have worked.

I am using a dual GPU setup with Intel and Nvidia, and the drivers are up to date. Proton versions 5 and below cause the game to crash with a Unity error, but the issue occurs with 5.13 and above, so no versions work. The operating system is Manjaro Linux.

I found out my Vulkan drivers are not working like they should. I am able to use the Intel one, but not the Nvidia one. So I need help on enabling that device would be appreciated. When I try to run `vulkaninfo` with Nvidia, I get

> ERROR at /build/vulkan-tools/src/Vulkan-Tools-1.2.159/vulkaninfo/vulkaninfo.h:248:vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormats2KHR failed with ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED

I know I'm running the Nvidia drivers, because I'm using the command `VK_ICD_FILENAMES=/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/nvidia_icd.json DISPLAY=:0 vulkaninfo` which sets the driver to be used as an environment variable.

Comment: Have you been to the Proton forums for this? Native support means the game is designed to run on this OS, while you're relying on some sort of emulation using Proton, and that is always a tricky subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution! Install the `optimus-manager` and `optimus-manager-qt` packages in Arch (might be from AUR). Follow the directions of [this article](https://medium.com/@jashaswimalyaacharjee/how-to-switch-between-nvidia-and-intel-graphics-completely-battery-saving-in-manjaro-b9254c8bf6af). You should be able to switch between Intel and Nvidia. The problem was that the Nvidia drivers weren't loading.